# Seaborn: Bar Plot w/ DivergingNorm/Cmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a list of values ranging from around -0.15 to 0.08:

```
array([-9.28024375e-03, -7.74566792e-03,  6.89222284e-02,  1.98236910e-03,
        1.05891798e-02,  7.36737261e-03,  6.25777898e-03, -1.78726642e-02,
       -5.06597295e-03,  5.17623104e-02, -1.13474442e-02,  1.06263056e-02,
        2.09431952e-03, -1.54730073e-02, -1.93402164e-02,  1.04915526e-02,
        2.04725155e-03,  2.65222141e-02,  1.43185909e-02, -3.73984434e-03,
        2.62798866e-02, -2.67092615e-02,  3.48239927e-02,  3.08109938e-03,
       -9.12865632e-03,  2.46767319e-03, -2.36669926e-02,  2.07367834e-02,
        3.06733189e-02, -5.56772675e-03, -2.40482345e-03, -4.24432795e-02,
       -3.79769064e-03,  2.51791666e-02,  2.32164137e-02, -1.74955467e-02,
        7.47313626e-03,  6.86957861e-03,  1.38965986e-02,  7.68997312e-05,
       -4.59857112e-03,  1.37564169e-02, -6.25312715e-03,  1.66797351e-02,
       -7.13480355e-03, -2.38543967e-02,  2.48704615e-02,  2.99393285e-02,
       -1.17281194e-03,  1.78675678e-03,  8.04761250e-03, -1.50505912e-01,
        8.25650062e-02])
```

Each of these values corresponds to a particular part of a sentence. I am trying to visualise this in a bar plot. I want all of the negative values to range from some orange -> red, and the positive values from some yellow -> green or maybe blue -> deep blue. I want the threshold of these values to be 0.00.

I've tried to use Matplotlib's `DivergingNorm` functionality to create this and pass it to my Seaborn plot. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at all and I get the following:

[image: Faulty saliency plot]

To create this, I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import seaborn as sns

divnorm = colors.DivergingNorm(vmin=df["saliency"].values.min(), vcenter=0, vmax=df["saliency"].values.max())
div_colors = plt.cm.RdYlGn(divnorm(df["saliency"])) 
ax = sns.barplot(x='saliency', y='tokens', data=df, palette=div_colors, edgecolor='black')
```

I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong or if I should be using a different scale but any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Updated with DataFrame values

```
            tokens  saliency
0               Go -0.009280
1               to -0.007746
2         Walmart,  0.068922
3              get  0.001982
4            shot.  0.010589
5               Go  0.007367
6               to  0.006258
7                a -0.017873
8           garlic -0.005066
9        festival,  0.051762
10             get -0.011347
11           shot.  0.010626
12              Go  0.002094
13              to -0.015473
14               a -0.019340
15        concert,  0.010492
16             get  0.002047
17           shot.  0.026522
18              Go  0.014319
19              to -0.003740
20         church,  0.026280
21             get -0.026709
22           shot.  0.034824
23              Go  0.003081
24              to -0.009129
25             the  0.002468
26         movies, -0.023667
27             get  0.020737
28           shot.  0.030673
29              Go -0.005568
30              to -0.002405
31           work, -0.042443
32             get -0.003798
33           shot.  0.025179
34              Go  0.023216
35              to -0.017496
36        college,  0.007473
37             get  0.006870
38           shot.  0.013897
39              Go  0.000077
40              to -0.004599
41         school,  0.013756
42             get -0.006253
43           shot.  0.016680
44              Go -0.007135
45              to -0.023854
46             the  0.024870
47            bar,  0.029939
48             get -0.001173
49           shot.  0.001787
50  #ThisIsAmerica  0.008048
51         #ElPaso -0.150506
52         #Dayton  0.082565
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of your dataframe? Does the 'token' column contain doubles?

Comment: @JohanC Sure, I've added code with my Dataframe printed. (I think I've just realised the problem, you were right. Is there any way for me to print doubles like this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a token has multiple saliencies, seaborn's barplot takes the average of these saliencies. So, not the original saliencies are shown, but the averages per token, together with an error bar.

To color them, you can first create the barplot, and in a second pass loop through the created bars and assign them a color depending on their width. (Note that in the latest matplotlib versions `DivergingNorm` has been renamed to `TwoSlopeNorm`.)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

saliency = np.array([-9.28024375e-03, -7.74566792e-03, 6.89222284e-02, 1.98236910e-03, 1.05891798e-02, 7.36737261e-03, 6.25777898e-03, -1.78726642e-02, -5.06597295e-03, 5.17623104e-02, -1.13474442e-02, 1.06263056e-02, 2.09431952e-03, -1.54730073e-02, -1.93402164e-02, 1.04915526e-02, 2.04725155e-03, 2.65222141e-02, 1.43185909e-02, -3.73984434e-03, 2.62798866e-02, -2.67092615e-02, 3.48239927e-02, 3.08109938e-03, -9.12865632e-03, 2.46767319e-03, -2.36669926e-02, 2.07367834e-02, 3.06733189e-02, -5.56772675e-03, -2.40482345e-03, -4.24432795e-02, -3.79769064e-03, 2.51791666e-02, 2.32164137e-02, -1.74955467e-02, 7.47313626e-03, 6.86957861e-03, 1.38965986e-02, 7.68997312e-05, -4.59857112e-03, 1.37564169e-02, -6.25312715e-03, 1.66797351e-02, -7.13480355e-03, -2.38543967e-02, 2.48704615e-02, 2.99393285e-02, -1.17281194e-03, 1.78675678e-03, 8.04761250e-03, -1.50505912e-01, 8.25650062e-02])
tokens = ['Go', 'to', 'Walmart,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'a', 'garlic', 'festival,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'a', 'concert,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'church,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'the', 'movies,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'work,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'college,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'school,', 'get', 'shot.', 'Go', 'to', 'the', 'bar,', 'get', 'shot.', '#ThisIsAmerica', '#ElPaso', '#Dayton']

ax = sns.barplot(x=saliency, y=tokens, edgecolor='black')

widths = np.array( [bar.get_width() for bar in ax.containers[0]])
divnorm = mpl.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=widths.min(), vcenter=0, vmax=widths.max())
div_colors = plt.cm.RdYlGn(divnorm(widths))
for bar, color in zip(ax.containers[0], div_colors):
    bar.set_facecolor(color)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Now, to obtain the colors from the question, you could create two linear colormaps, one for the negatives and one for the positives.

```py
widths = np.array([bar.get_width() for bar in ax.containers[0]])
neg_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['orange', 'red'])
pos_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['yellow', 'green'])
min_width, max_width = widths.min(), widths.max()
for bar, w in zip(ax.containers[0], widths):
    bar.set_facecolor(neg_cmap(w / min_width) if w < 0 else pos_cmap(w / max_width))
```

[image: using LinearSegmentedColormap]

Comment: I think it might be easier to do a groupby on the original dataset and then push the mean values through the colormap?